# matching a regular expression containing *,_

Tags: regex

I want to match a regular expression something like this,

```
 *2copy, NM_121
```

but my data also contains digits like 12345 and when i try to match the above value it matches other digits like 12345 which i don't want to match.
Please help me out with this.

Comment: Please post the regex you tried so we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape a `*` like this: `\*`. For example, to match a word starting with `*2`, you'd do `\*2.*`, not `*2.*` (depending on if you're using this from within another language you may need to double escape). '_' shouldn't need escaping.

If you post the offending regex we'll be able to help you better.

Comment: This is my regular expression.. val = val.replaceAll("^[^0-9]*","<a href=\"north_revenue.jsp?channel="+ val+"&date="+ date + "\">"+val+"</a>");

Comment: So....what patterns are you trying to match? Your current regex `^[^0-9]*` matches *any* string that doesn't start with numbers, and the exact match will be all non-numerals from the start of the string up to the first numeral. What's your question?

Comment: Actually i have patterns like *2copy,bnm_123,Hello,ONE97_234 . Basically its a table where values are stored for these,and those values are like 234,256,7789 etc. What i have to do is to make a link for these patterns like *2copy etc so that when i click on these,some other jsp files should open with parameters like name of variable,i.e *2copy,so here i am replacing it with a href. Now the problem what i am facing is that while replacing those variables,their integer values i.e 234,276 etc are also getting replaced which i dont want.

Comment: Now when i do this replacement *2copy, bnm_123 etc is getting displayed as *2copy2copy, bnm_123nm_123..! I guess it is replacing the first non digit character with a link,i.e bnm_123 becomes a link whereas the suffix which is getting added to it,i.e nm_123 remains as a normal value,making my table display 2 times the same name,one being a link and the other one as normal value.

Comment: Of course that's what's happening...that's what your regex says should happen. You could try `^[^0-9]\w+` to match any whole word that doesn't start with a number.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i have a string like BNM-QPD,where this regex is matching as BNM-QPDQPD,where BNM-QPD is a link and the string following "-" is repeated

Comment: It's a bit hard to advise on potential problems in your find-replace when you haven't given us any code to go off - why don't you update your original question to include your snippet of code that's causing the problem, as well as exactly what the problem is?